# Change mail from header in sendmail

Tags: dns, email, sendmail

We have two separate RTs (request trackers) configured on one server. They both are configured to send the emails through `sendmail`. We are trying to configure now SPF and DMARC records for these DNS names. What we achieved for now is that SPF passes but DMARC fails. If I understood correctly the reason for DMARC fail is that `From` header of the email is set to `support@dns.name.rt1` while `Envelope From` header is set to `apache@server.dns.name`. `server.dns.name` is added in the SPF record as the trusted one, so SPF passes.

Is there an option in `sendmail` to set `Envelope From` header the same as `From`? In other words we need it to be set dynamically to `support@dns.name.rt1` or `sales@dns.name.rt2`.

What I have currently found is using masquerade feature, but if I understood correctly only one DNS can be used there.

Or is there an option for DMARC to pass with the current difference in the domains in `From` headers?

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to make your DMARC fit around bad data.

Sounds like you are using SMTP from RT. IIRC RT recommend a CLI invocation for outgoing mail - then you can easily set up a pipeline with (say) awk or Perl to rewrite the header FROM address, and then pass this on to `sendmail -t -i` (IIRC `sendmail -f` only forces the envelope from address).

Comment: RT is from Best Practical. I have found an option in the config file: `# Set($SendmailBounceArguments , '-f "<>"');`. Haven't tried it yet, but I guess this is what's needed. However, I was told one more surprise one of the RTs has queus with two different domains: so from one request tracker the emails are sent from `support@domain1` and from `support@domain2`. And I've got no ideas how to rule this case....

Comment: Isn't that what I just explicitly said won't solve the problem?

Comment: my bad, sorry. you're right. gonna try your idea